# How to call module.exports from handler in AWS Lambda (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

That's what says in AWS:

> The module-name.export value in your function. For example,
>   "index.handler" calls exports.handler in index.js.

And it correctly calls this function:

```
exports.handler = (username, password) => {
    ...
}
```

But what if the code is like this:

```
module.exports = (username, password) => {
    ...
}
```

How do I call it? Nothing I tried works like `module.exports`, `module.handler`, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AWS Lambda expects your module to export an object that contains a handler function. In your Lambda configuration you then declare the file that contains the module, and the name of the handler function.

The way modules are exported in Node.js is via the `module.exports` property. The return value of a `require` call is the contents of the `module.exports` property at the end of the file evaluation.

`exports` is just a local variable pointing to `module.exports`. You should avoid using `exports`, and instead use `module.exports`, since some other piece of code may overwrite `module.exports`, leading to unexpected behaviour.

In your first code example, the module correctly exports an object with a single function `handler`. In the second code example, however, your code exports a single function. Since this does not match AWS Lambda's API, this does not work.

Consider the following two files, export_object.js and export_function.js:

```
// export_object.js

function internal_foo () {
    return 1;
}

module.exports.foo = internal_foo;
```

and

```
// export_function.js

function internal_foo () {
    return 1;
}

module.exports = internal_foo;
```

When we run `require('export_object.js')` we get an object with a single function:

```
> const exp = require('./export_object.js')
undefined
> exp
{ foo: [Function: internal_foo] }
```

Compare that with the result we get when we run `require('export_function.js')`, where we just get a function:

```
> const exp = require('./export_funntion.js')
undefined
> exp
[Function: internal_foo]
```

When you configure AWS Lambda to run a function called `handler`, that is exported in a module defined in the file `index.js`, here is an approximation of Amazon does when a function is called:

```
const handler_module = require('index.js');
return handler_module.handler(event, context, callback);
```

The important part there is the call to the handler function defined in the module.

Comment: The example is not well tied to what handler does. The steps in between should be explicit. module.exports.foo = internal_foo => module.exports.handler, which makes it clear that Amazon will execute what's in handler.

Comment: What do you mean @KenIngram? I think this answer perfectly answers the question and brings clarity as to what AWS expects and how NodeJS works

Answer (score 2):

I have used like this.

```
//index.js

const user = require('./user').user;
const handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  user.login(username, password)
    .then((success) => {
      //success
    })
    .catch(() => {
      //error
    });
};

exports.handler = handler;



//user.js
const user = {
  login(username, password) {
   return new BPromise((resolve, reject) => {
     //do what you want.
   });
  }
};
export {user};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define or export your handler function.

```
exports.handler = (username, password) => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call `exports.handler` what actually happens, is the module looks for a property called `handler` in the `module.exports` object, when it doesnt find it (since handler is not a property of `module.exports`), it creates one for us with the property name being whatever comes after `exports.` so use whatever you want, handler is not special to AWS.

```
try it yourself:
make a new test.js file and copy the following code:
```

```
exports.handler = () => {
    console.log('hello from exports.handler')
}
exports.vinnyLovesJS = () => {
    console.log('Vinny loves JS!');
    (($) => { $('THIS is crazy! :)') })((a) => { console.log(a) }, 
    console.log('I do! But...'))
}
module.exports.handler();
module.exports.vinnyLovesJS();
```

Now run the code with:

```
`node test.js`
```

Output:

```
hello from exports.handler
Vinny loves JS!
I do! But...
THIS is crazy! :)
```

enjoy the extra JS craziness!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use typescript with an Amazon skill and are getting this issue, it's likely that your event handler is being compiled to a sub-folder and not in your main directory.

By default, AWS looks for your event handler in the root directory of your `lambda` folder. However, if you are using typescript and compile your output to a `build` folder, you need to change where AWS looks for your handler. Modify `ask-resources.json` in the root directory of your skill from:

```
// ...
"skillInfrastructure": {
    "userConfig": {
        "runtime": "nodejs10.x",
        "handler": "index.handler",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    },
    "type": "@ask-cli/lambda-deployer"
}
// ...
```

to

```
// ...
"skillInfrastructure": {
    "userConfig": {
        "runtime": "nodejs10.x",
        "handler": "build/index.handler",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    },
    "type": "@ask-cli/lambda-deployer"
}
// ...
```