# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

1. Trying to create a AWS lambda that will insert into a DynamoDB table.

2 .Tried changing up the import/require

//Where I use it

```
const { ReportRepo } = require("../repos/reportsRepo");
const { withProcessEnv } = require("../util/dynamoDb");

const _client = withProcessEnv(process.env);
const _repo = new ReportRepo(_client);
```

//DynamoDB client

```
const { DocumentClient } = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");

const withProcessEnv = ({
  AWS_ENDPOINT,
  AWS_REGION,
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
}) => () => {
  const options = {
    endpoint: AWS_ENDPOINT,
    region: AWS_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  };

  return new DocumentClient(options);
};

module.exports = withProcessEnv;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639302/how-to-call-module-exports-from-handler-in-aws-lambda-node-js) (Lambda expecting `module.exports` to be augmented with properties and not overwritten).

Comment: @StockOverflaw I am using exports somewhere else in my code. Do you think thats the cause of this?

Comment: Unless it's in the same file, I'd say no: `module.exports` is supposed to be local to the file being loaded through `require`. Even in the context of Lambda AFAIK.

Comment: @StockOverflaw I thought so as well. So not sure why this is not working.

Comment: This is somehow inconsistent: you have an error about assigning to a readonly prop, but in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58256095/1269732), you comment that you get an error about `module.exports` being `undefined`. These 2 errors don't seem compatible: ensure you test all combinations already proposed in the exact same environment (files saved, etc.), other than that I'm lost here! :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to export object in DynamoDB client.

**module.exports = {withProcessEnv};**

```js
const { DocumentClient } = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");

const withProcessEnv = ({
  AWS_ENDPOINT,
  AWS_REGION,
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
}) => () => {
  const options = {
    endpoint: AWS_ENDPOINT,
    region: AWS_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  };

  return new DocumentClient(options);
};

module.exports = {withProcessEnv};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.handler = withProcessEnv;
```

Check https://stackify.com/aws-lambda-with-node-js-a-complete-getting-started-guide/

Comment: try with exports.handler = withProcessEnv; instead

Comment: Tried this and got "Cannot set property 'handler' of undefined".   const {handler} = require()

Comment: have you tried with export or exports? I edited the answer

Comment: remove the module. "handler not a function" const { handler } = require("../util/dynamoDb");

const _client = handler(process.env);

Comment: what handler have you chosen for the lambda (you can check in aws lambda console)?

Comment: The dynamodb client is not a lambda. I am just trying to use it in my lambda